# Permission to access open document's enclosing folder in macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, file

I am trying to make a Mac app where the user can open a document file and use keys or menus to scroll through the next/previous files in the directory (as some image viewer apps do with images).

I was trying to do this by getting the folder URL for the current main document window, and getting the list of files in the folder in order. But it seems I can't get permission to do this. I run

```
fullPaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
```

and I get the error:

```
The file “Journal DF” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

"Journal DF" is a folder. I have read/write permissions on it.

I found an [Apple developer thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/96062) that suggests this might have to do with sandboxing: although I'm getting the open document *itself* from an NSOpenPanel, I'm not getting the folder contents from that panel, so it doesn't want to give me permission. It looks like I could change a setting to turn off this sandboxing, which would mean the file couldn't go in the Mac App Store. This is an app mainly intended for my personal use, so I'll do that if I have to, but is there any more elegant way to access the contents of the open document's folder?

Here is the result of ls -lea@hO on a folder that gives the error:

```
total 8480
drwxr-xr-x@  26 Main  staff  -  832B Jul  3 11:28 .
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
drwxrwxrwx@ 267 Main  staff  -  8.3K Aug  7 08:30 ..
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   10K Jul  3 11:28 .DS_Store
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
drwxr-xr-x   11 Main  staff  -  352B Jul 29 18:19 Current Skeletons
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   30K May 24 16:14 Foundation sources and opposition.xlsx
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
    com.apple.quarantine      30B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   34K Apr  8  2018 Foundations Lucidchart 8-Apr-2018.pdf
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42B 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms     1.2K 
    com.apple.quarantine      68B 
-rw-------@   1 Main  staff  -   22K Feb 19  2018 Foundations Lucidchart.pdf
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42B 
    com.apple.quarantine      32B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  261K Feb 19  2018 Foundations Lucidchart.vdx
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42B 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms     1.2K 
    com.apple.quarantine      68B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   61K Feb  6  2016 Foundations Skeleton 5.tbx
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  151K Apr 28  2015 Journal Foundations A.md
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B 
    com.apple.quarantine      21B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
    com.metaclassy.byword.selectedRange   10B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  500K Apr 15  2016 Journal Foundations C (Dakini's conflicted copy 2016-04-15).md
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  528K Jun  5  2017 Journal Foundations C.md
    com.apple.TextEncoding    15B 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B 
    com.apple.quarantine      21B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
    com.metaclassy.byword.selectedRange   11B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  736K Sep 25  2017 Journal Foundations D.md
    com.apple.TextEncoding    15B 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B 
    com.apple.quarantine      21B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
    com.metaclassy.byword.selectedRange   11B 
drwxr-xr-x@ 524 Main  staff  -   16K Nov 25  2017 Journal Foundations E
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
drwxr-xr-x@ 765 Main  staff  -   24K Dec 10  2017 Journal Foundations F
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
drwxr-xr-x@ 885 Main  staff  -   28K May 25  2018 Journal Foundations G
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
drwxr-xr-x@ 682 Main  staff  -   21K Sep  8  2018 Journal Foundations H
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
drwxr-xr-x@ 641 Main  staff  -   20K Jun 26 14:41 Journal Foundations I
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  528K May 28  2017 Journal Synthesis A.md
    com.apple.TextEncoding    15B 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B 
    com.apple.quarantine      21B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
    com.metaclassy.byword.selectedRange   10B 
drwxr-xr-x  213 Main  staff  -  6.7K Apr 17 21:40 Old Skeletons
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -  1.2M May 17  2017 Reflect alias
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--    1 Main  staff  -   16K Jun 24  2017 True Foundations 1Sk.mellel
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   19K Feb  6  2018 True Foundations 2Sk.mellel
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_od4iyi2dtvvg7c4mdb6hnpcupi   105B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   13K Aug 27  2014 foundations.mellel
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B 
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   13K May 10  2017 old discussion from pipeline.mellel
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B 
-rw-r--r--@   1 Main  staff  -   46K May 14  2017 parameter zero.mellel
    com.dropbox.attributes    83B
```

Comment: "the user can open a document file and use keys or menus"  I don't understand your question.  How do you go from "opening a document" to "using keys or menus"?  What is a document and what are keys and menus?  And how do you go from opening a file to opening a folder?  "I'm getting the open document itself from an NSOpenPanel"  Where?  We don't see it.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is related to sandboxing. Either turn it off or set a security scoped bookmark after accessing the item in `NSOpenPanel`

Comment: El Tomato: User presses cmd-O or selects Open from the File menu to pull up an NSOpenPanel to open a file. Once that file is open, I want the user to be able to select the next or previous file in the folder, by pressing the keys cmd-[/cmd-] or by going to the File menu and selecting Next or Previous. I have added these options to the interface so that they call IBActions named nextNote and prevNote in the ViewController. So far I can't set these IBActions to find the next or previous file in the folder because the app has no permission to access the folder (or so the error message says).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vadian's comment was correct: it is indeed about sandboxing. I looked up [the process for security-scoped bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) and it seems *way* more complicated than I want to deal with, given that this app is primarily for my personal use. So I went into the .entitlements file and changed App Sandbox from YES to NO, and now it works as it was supposed to. That's good enough for me. If other people are having this problem and need to use the App Store, well, [here's the info on security-scoped bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) and I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, let's check if that Apple thread fits your situation or not.

Compile your app, once compiled, give it full disk access via:

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy,

by adding it to the Full Disk Access applications list. (You are eliminating the first layer of security and allowing your app to access your Documents folder, pictures folder, desktop folder, music folder, contact folder and another 3 or 4 protected folders.

Attempt 1) Run it and try to browser files with it on any folder *inside your home dir*. See if it works or not.

Attempt 2) Also is valid to test it to browse files on any usb stick (because they don't have permissions flags). See if it works on USB Sticks

If it still says you don't have permissions, post your results and more details about your system version, and if possible, a result from terminal of the command  `ls -lea@hO /path/to/folder` of the folder where it is giving error, so we can check the Unix/ACL and sandbox permissions of that folder.

Comment: OK. So I don't see a Full Disk Access applications list in Security & Privacy (I am running High Sierra - is that a Mojave thing?) And I am getting this same error on a USB stick. Even on the stick it says, "The file “NO NAME” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

It does this on every directory I have tried this on: on the stick, in my Dropbox, on the hard drive. I don't have space for the terminal result here so I will add it above.